# jooq insert throws an exception when another thread is reading from same table

Tags: java, jooq

I have a table where I am inserting records using record.insert() method. I believe this method is doing an insert and then a select but in a different transactions. At the same time I have another thread which pools this table for records processes them and then deletes them.

In some cases I am getting the below exception:

```
org.jooq.exception.NoDataFoundException: Exactly one row expected for refresh. Record does not exist in database.
at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.refresh(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:345)
at org.jooq.impl.TableRecordImpl.getReturningIfNeeded(TableRecordImpl.java:232)
at org.jooq.impl.TableRecordImpl.storeInsert0(TableRecordImpl.java:208)
at org.jooq.impl.TableRecordImpl$1.operate(TableRecordImpl.java:169)
```

My solution was to use DSL.using(configuration()).insertInto instead of record.insert().

My question is shouldn't the insert and fetch be done in the same transaction?

UPDATE:
This is a dropwizard app that is using jooqbundle: com.bendb.dropwizard:dropwizard-jooq.

The configuration is injected in the DAO, the insert is as follows:

```
R object = // jooq record
object.attach(configuration);
object.insert();
```

On the second thread I am just selecting some records from this table, processing them and then deleting them

Jooq logs clearly shows that the 2 queries are not run in same transaction:

```
14:07:09.550 [main] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener - -> with bind values      : insert into "queue"
....
14:07:09.083', 1)
14:07:09.589 [main] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener - Affected row(s)          : 1
14:07:09.590 [main] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.StopWatch - Query executed           : Total: 47.603ms
14:07:09.591 [main] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.StopWatch - Finishing                : Total: 48.827ms, +1.223ms
14:07:09.632 [main] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener - Executing query          : select "queue"."
```

I do not see the "autocommit off" or "savepoint" statements in the logs which are generally printed by jooq in case the queries are run in a transaction. I hope this helps, let me know if you need more info

UPDATE 2:

Jooq version is 3.9.1
mysql version 5.6.23

Database and jooq entry yml file:

```
database:
  driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  user: ***
  password: ***
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mySchema
  properties:
    charSet: UTF-8
    characterEncoding: UTF-8
  # the maximum amount of time to wait on an empty pool before throwing an exception
  maxWaitForConnection: 1s
  # the SQL query to run when validating a connection's liveness
  validationQuery: "SELECT 1"
  # the timeout before a connection validation queries fail
  validationQueryTimeout: 3s
  # initial number of connections
  initialSize: 25
  # the minimum number of connections to keep open
  minSize: 25
  # the maximum number of connections to keep open
  maxSize: 25
  # whether or not idle connections should be validated
  checkConnectionWhileIdle: true
  # the amount of time to sleep between runs of the idle connection validation, abandoned cleaner and idle pool resizing
  evictionInterval: 10s
  # the minimum amount of time an connection must sit idle in the pool before it is eligible for eviction
  minIdleTime: 1 minute

jooq:
  # The flavor of SQL to generate. If not specified, it will be inferred from the JDBC connection URL.  (default: null)
  dialect: MYSQL
  # Whether to write generated SQL to a logger before execution.  (default: no)
  logExecutedSql: no
  # Whether to include schema names in generated SQL.  (default: yes)
  renderSchema: yes
  # How names should be rendered in generated SQL.  One of QUOTED, AS_IS, LOWER, or UPPER.  (default: QUOTED)
  renderNameStyle: QUOTED
  # How keywords should be rendered in generated SQL.  One of LOWER, UPPER.  (default: UPPER)
  renderKeywordStyle: UPPER
  # Whether generated SQL should be pretty-printed.  (default: no)
  renderFormatted: no
  # How parameters should be represented.  One of INDEXED, NAMED, or INLINE.  (default: INDEXED)
  paramType: INDEXED
  # How statements should be generated; one of PREPARED_STATEMENT or STATIC_STATEMENT.  (default: PREPARED_STATEMENT)
  statementType: PREPARED_STATEMENT
  # Whether internal jOOQ logging should be enabled.  (default: no)
  executeLogging: no
  # Whether optimistic locking should be enabled.  (default: no)
  executeWithOptimisticLocking: yes
  # Whether returned records should be 'attached' to the jOOQ context.  (default: yes)
  attachRecords: yes
  # Whether primary-key fields should be updatable.  (default: no)
  updatablePrimaryKeys: no
```

Have included the jooq bundle in the Application class as described in https://github.com/benjamin-bader/droptools/tree/master/dropwizard-jooq.
Using https://github.com/xvik/dropwizard-guicey to inject the configuration into each DAO.
The guide module has the following binding:

```
bind(Configuration.class).toInstance(jooqBundle.getConfiguration());
```

Comment: Can you post the full code that leads to this behaviour, including how you set up your `configuration()`?

Comment: This is a dropwizard app that is using jooqbundle:         com.bendb.dropwizard:dropwizard-jooq.

Comment: What jOOQ version and what database are you using? Also, it would really be helpful if you posted your configuration setup. There might be important bits in the configuration, including your `Settings` and `ConnectionProvider`

Comment: Added the requested info

Comment: @LukasEder do you need any more info from my side?

Comment: Sorry for being quiet here. I'm not sure what the problem is, I don't know Dropwizard well enough to see if there's a problem on their side (which it probably is). Hoping that someone else will see this question.